# Simpler Substitute Solution From Range In Column Within Formula W/ Other Parameters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Thanks ahead of time for any ideas!

I have a formula I'm utilizing to trim down on selection of words I'd like to eliminate from an output using SUBSTITUTE:

`=ArrayFormula(sort(unique(trim(lower(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(flatten(split(B:B," ")),A2,""),A3,""),A4,""),A5,""),A6,""),A7,""),A8,""),A9,""),A10,""))))))`

As I go through my process, the words for substitution grows, leading to the necessity of adding yet another substitute to my formula.

If there's any other ingenious way of not having to do this, but rather consider any word in Column A for substitution, that'd be optimal.

Here's some sample data; and please don't hesitate with any questions, or thoughts:

- [20230202 stack exchange substitute better solution question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T8ro_N9A0BJJ--DqFOce8BC-UhDMBJqDCWuDa29flMc/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
=SORT(LAMBDA(words,UNIQUE(FILTER(words,NOT(COUNTIF(A2:A,words)))))(FLATTEN(IFERROR(SPLIT(B2:B," ")))))
```

Comment: Fantastic ztiaa! Thanks much for the help. I'll peel through what's happening in the formula to enhance my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Try `QUERY()` formula with few others functions.

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(FLATTEN(INDEX(SPLIT(B2:INDEX(B2:B,COUNTA(B2:B))," ")))),
"where not Col1 matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",1,A2:INDEX(A2:A,COUNTA(A2:A))) & "|^$' order by Col1",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Harun24hr! I prefer utilizing QUERY, and should have thought to filter out utilizing the function.